# Multi-master DNS name Servers

Tags: linux, dns, hosting, nameservers, bind9

Is there a possibility to configure a two **primary** dns name_servers in the same domain_name like: `dns1.exmaple.com` and `dns2.example.com`?

best regards.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is the convention. In your example, there would be subdomain A records in the example.com DNS record:

```
; A records for Name Servers
ns1   IN   A   <IP address of ns1 server>
ns2   IN   A   <IP addrses of ns2 server>
```

Also, if you are asking whether one of them has to be a slave to another, at least with Bind, they do not.  When Bind is answering DNS requests, it is basing the answers on zone files locally stored on each server. The slaving part is just for convenience, ensuring the local files on the two machines are always matched.

If both servers are configured to be primary servers, and if you always update both servers to have the same local zone files, it will work fine.

Comment: Be careful answering questions like these. Some in the community feel answers should be downvoted, too. Also see [Should one downvote answers to off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194963/173448)